# How to describe the use of 'them' with nouns?

Tags: single-word-requests, descriptive-grammar

I'm looking for a short and precise word to describe the use of the pronoun *them* with plurals, i.e.

*Let's kill **them zombies**!*

***Them townsfolk** sure are full of baloney.*

*I hate **them bees**.*

It appears to be a fairly common solecism (?) in some areas/communities. It's also quite common in prose and pop culture. Does this convention have a name?

> Inhabitants of the rural mid-west of Foobarland are in the habit of prefixing nouns with the word *them*, using the combined phrase as the subject or the object of a sentence. Descriptive grammarians refer to this pattern as the/a _______.

Answer (score 1):

This is [demonstrative *them*](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/demonstrative-them), as explained by the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project  English in North America.

It’s called this because *them* is being used as a determiner, the same way that *those* is used in “standard” English.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks! The link is very informative. More so than the answers to the question I unwittingly duplicated.